# Upgrade DNN 9.0.1 to 9.2 Failing at PersonaBar

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We are upgrading our DNN installation to 9.4.4 to take advantage of the latest memory leak fix. However, we are having trouble and despite trying several upgrade paths I am making no progress.

I originally followed the suggested upgrade path and went to 9.1.1 but had problems with Newtonsoft.Json.dll. I saw in a forum post somewhere that going straight to 9.2 might be easier because Newtonsoft.Json is upgraded to version 10.0.3 in that version of dnn across all modules - my extensions go to 9.0.0 so figured I'd just upgrade the package across the entire site.

I still had the Newtonsoft.Json error so I updated my web.config file as per the steps taken [here](https://github.com/dnnsoftware/Dnn.Platform/issues/2121) - my assembly binding redirect is now

```
   <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="Newtonsoft.Json" publicKeyToken="30ad4fe6b2a6aeed" />
     <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-32767.32767.32767.32767" newVersion="10.0.0" />
   </dependentAssembly>
```

(10.0.3 nuget package has v10.0.0 of dll)

I have 10.0.0 of Newtonsoft.Json.dll in the /bin folder at the website root.

But I still get a failure at PersonaBar - the download progress pauses at 50% every time, getting 500 errors from the server.

Install report:

```
02/22/2020 12:21:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Applying Upgrade Script 09.01.00
02/22/2020 12:21:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:17 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:17 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:17 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Applying Upgrade Script 09.01.01
02/22/2020 12:21:17 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.01.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:17 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.01.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:18 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.01.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:18 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.01.01.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:18 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Applying Upgrade Script 09.02.00
02/22/2020 12:21:18 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.02.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:18 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.02.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:19 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End ExecuteScript:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.02.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:19 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpgradeVersion:D:\home\site\au\Providers\DataProviders\SqlDataProvider\09.02.00.SqlDataProvider
02/22/2020 12:21:19 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Upgrading Application to 9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:19 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start Application Upgrades: 9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:19 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Host Settings
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Site Management
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Schedule
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Superuser Accounts
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Extensions
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Device Detection Management
02/22/2020 12:21:20 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//Extensions
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//SiteSettings
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//SecurityRoles
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//Taxonomy
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//SiteRedirectionManagement
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//DevicePreviewManagement
02/22/2020 12:21:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//SearchAdmin
02/22/2020 12:21:23 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Upgrading Application to 9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start Application Upgrades: 9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Upgrading Application to 9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start Application Upgrades: 9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//SearchEngineSiteMap
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//Solutions
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveAdminPages://Admin//BulkEmail
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Marketplace
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Module Definitions
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start RemoveHostPage:Portals
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start AddHostPage:Superuser Accounts
02/22/2020 12:21:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start AddPage:Superuser Accounts
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start AddModuleToPage:15
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End AddModuleToPage:15
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Updating Config for 9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:09.01.00
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:09.01.00
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Updating Config for 9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:09.01.01
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:21:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:09.01.01
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Updating Config for 9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:09.02.00
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start UpdateConfig:9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade End UpdateConfig:09.02.00
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Deleting Older Files for 9.1.0
02/22/2020 12:21:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start DeleteFiles:09.01.00
02/22/2020 12:21:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Deleting Older Files for 9.1.1
02/22/2020 12:21:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start DeleteFiles:09.01.01
02/22/2020 12:21:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Deleting Older Files for 9.2.0
02/22/2020 12:21:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start DeleteFiles:09.02.00
02/22/2020 12:21:50 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Upgrading Application
02/22/2020 12:21:54 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DDRMenu_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:21:54 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DDRMenu_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:21:57 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:21:58 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - Dnn.EditBar.UI_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:21:58 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.EditBar.UI_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:21:59 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:21:59 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:22:09 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - Dnn.PersonaBar.UI_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:09 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.UI_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start AddNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start AddNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start AddNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start AddNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start RemoveNode:
02/22/2020 12:22:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:22:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - DNNCE_01_Web.Deprecated_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_01_Web.Deprecated_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Connector - DNNCE_AzureConnector_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_AzureConnector_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:29 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_Console_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:29 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_Console_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:30 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_CoreMessaging_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:30 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_CoreMessaging_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_DigitalAssetsManagement_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_DigitalAssetsManagement_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:40 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_HtmlEditorManager_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:40 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_HtmlEditorManager_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:42 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_HTML_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:42 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_HTML_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:48 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_Journal_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:48 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_Journal_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:51 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_MemberDirectory_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:51 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_MemberDirectory_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:55 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_ModuleCreator_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:22:55 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_ModuleCreator_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:08 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_RazorHost_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:08 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_RazorHost_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - DNNCE_SiteExportImport_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_SiteExportImport_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Module - DNNCE_SocialGroups_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_SocialGroups_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:25 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - DNNCE_Website.Deprecated_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:25 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\DNNCE_Website.Deprecated_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:25 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - Newtonsoft.Json_10.00.03_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:25 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Newtonsoft.Json_10.00.03_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Library - Telerik_09.01.01_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:26 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Telerik_09.01.01_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:32 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=path
02/22/2020 12:23:32 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:32 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:32 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=path
02/22/2020 12:23:32 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing JavaScript_Library - jQuery.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:33 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\JavaScriptLibrary\jQuery.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing JavaScript_Library - Selectize.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:34 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\JavaScriptLibrary\Selectize.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Provider - AspNetClientCapabilityProvider_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:35 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Provider\AspNetClientCapabilityProvider_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:36 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:36 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:37 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Provider - DNNCE_FolderProviders_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:37 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Provider\DNNCE_FolderProviders_09.02.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:39 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:23:40 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing Provider - DNNConnect.CKEditorProvider_01.00.04_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:23:40 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Provider\DNNConnect.CKEditorProvider_01.00.04_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:21 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.XmlMerge Start UpdateNode: keyAttribute=name
02/22/2020 12:24:42 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.AdminLogs_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:42 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.AdminLogs_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:43 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.ConfigConsole_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:43 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.ConfigConsole_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:45 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Connectors_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:45 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Connectors_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:46 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.CssEditor_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:46 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.CssEditor_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:48 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Extensions_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:48 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Extensions_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Licensing_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:49 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Licensing_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:50 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Prompt_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:50 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Prompt_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:53 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Recyclebin_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:53 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Recyclebin_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:54 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Roles_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:54 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Roles_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:56 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Security_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:56 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Security_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:58 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Seo_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:58 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Seo_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:59 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Servers_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:24:59 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Servers_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:01 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteSettings_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:01 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteSettings_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:02 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Sites_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:02 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Sites_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:04 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.SqlConsole_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:04 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.SqlConsole_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:06 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.TaskScheduler_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:06 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.TaskScheduler_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:07 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:07 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Themes_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:09 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Users_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:09 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Users_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:11 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Vocabularies_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:11 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Vocabularies_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:13 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing JavaScript_Library - jQueryMigrate.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:13 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\JavaScriptLibrary\jQueryMigrate.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:13 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing JavaScript_Library - jQueryUI.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:13 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\JavaScriptLibrary\jQueryUI.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:14 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.Pages_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:15 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.Pages_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Internals.Steps.BaseInstallationStep Installing PersonaBar - Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteImportExport_01.05.00_Install.zip
02/22/2020 12:25:16 [INFO] DotNetNuke.Services.Upgrade.Upgrade Start InstallPackage:D:\home\site\au\Install\Module\Dnn.PersonaBar.SiteImportExport_01.05.00_Install.zip
```

Logs:

```
2020-02-22 12:21:23,629 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - ExceptionSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
2020-02-22 12:21:23,676 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
2020-02-22 12:21:23,910 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - ExceptionSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
2020-02-22 12:21:23,926 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
2020-02-22 12:21:24,052 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Installer.Log.Logger - ExceptionSystem.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
2020-02-22 12:21:24,066 [RD0003FF4888B3][Thread:37][ERROR] DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.Exceptions - System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Dnn.Modules.Dashboard.Components.Installers.DashboardInstaller.UnInstall()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you check your newtonsoft.dll versions. Third party modules can mess this up by overwriting the dll to a newer version.

I had a similar problem a while ago, [this](https://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/threadid/543186/scope/posts/persona-bar-not-displaying-completely) worked for me.

Also check the troubleshooting guidelines on [DNN Docs](https://dnndocs.com/content/guides/tutorials/troubleshooting/ts-missing-persona-bar/index.html).

Anyway: have you already tried to upgrade from 9.0.1 to 9.4.4 directly (make sure .Net Framework 4.7.2 ist installed on your server, otherwise you'll run into problems)? The suggested upgrade path is what it's called: suggested.